# defining a topology by its compact sets

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness

**The goal.**  Let $X$ be a set endowed with Hausdorff topologies $\tau_w$ and $\tau_n$, such that $\tau_w\subseteq\tau_n$.  Let $\mathscr{C}$ denote a family of subsets $A\subseteq X$, which satisfies the following properties.

(i)  $\mathscr{C}$ is closed under arbitrary intersections and finite unions;

(ii)  every $\tau_n$-compact set belongs to $\mathscr{C}$; and

(iii)  every $A\in\mathscr{C}$ is $\tau_w$-compact.

I would like to define a new topology $\tau_\mathscr{C}$ on $X$ which satisfies the following properties.

(1)  $\tau_w\subseteq\tau_\mathscr{C}\subseteq\tau_n$;

(2)  every $\tau_\mathscr{C}$ compact set belongs to $\mathscr{C}$; and

(3)  every $A\in\mathscr{C}$ is $\tau_\mathscr{C}$-compact.

**Discussion.**

The obvious thing to try is to take the intersection $\tau_\cap$ of all topologies $\tau$ satisfying $\tau_w\subseteq\tau\subseteq\tau_n$ and for which every $\tau$-compact set belongs to $\mathscr{C}$.  However, it is far from obvious that $\tau_\cap$ would satisfy (2) or (3).

Probably this is not possible in general.  However, we could assume that $X$ is a Banach space, $\tau_n$ is the norm topology, and $\tau_w$ is the weak topology.  We could also, if necessary, impose some additional assumptions on $\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that $\tau_\cap$ satisfies $(2)$? I mean, it's the intersection of all topologies satisfying $(1)$ and $(2)$... Therefore, there exists such a topology if and only if the finest such that $(3)$ holds is finer than $\tau_\cap$.

Comment: Well, that $\tau_\cap$ satisfies (2) may well be true, and it may have an elementary and/or routine proof.  However, it is not sufficiently obvious that I can see it!

Comment: It may help if I explicitly defined $\mathscr{C}$, although the definition may be hard to understand for non-functional-analysts.  We let $1\leq\xi<\omega_1$ be a countable ordinal and denote by $\mathcal{S}_\xi$ the $\xi$-order Schreier family.  We then define $\mathscr{C}$ by letting $A\subseteq X$ belong to $\mathscr{C}$ if and only if every sequence $(x_n)\subseteq A$ admits a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ which converges weakly to some $x\in A$, and for which given $\epsilon>0$ there is a convex combination $(a_k)$ with support in $\mathcal{S}_\xi$ such that $\|x-\sum a_kx_{n_k}\|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Ah, you're right. It's not obvious at all... Sorry

Comment: @Ben It seems I've made at least two mistakes in my tentative approach. First one: I forgot to consider the supremum of the empty family. When such supremum is taken in $I=[\tau_w,\tau_n]$ it gives $\tau_w$, but when taken in $L_n=I\cap (2)$ it does not give $\tau_w$ unless $\mathscr{C}$ is the set of $\tau_w$-compact sets. Hence $L_n$ does not inherit arbitrary suprema from $I$ (this was used to show that $L_n$ has also arbitrary infima, a claim that I must retract now). [continues...]

Comment: Second one: assuming that $L_n$ has nonetheless all suprema (i.e. assuming that the supremum in $L_n$ of the empty family exists, that is, assuming that there is $\tau_0\in L_n$ such that for each $\tau\in L_n$ we have $\tau_0\subseteq \tau$) we can then apply the theorem of lattice theory and deduce that $L_n$ has also arbitrary infima, but the infimum in $L_n$ is not the same as the infimum in $I$ (this is related to the fact that $L_n$ does not inherit suprema). [continues...]

Comment: Assuming then the existence of $\tau_0$, the infimum in $L_n$ of a family $\tau_i\in L_n$ is the topology generated by $\cup\{\tau\in L_n\mid \tau\subseteq \tau_i\;\forall i\}$. In particular, the infimum of $L_n$ is $\tau_0$. I am very sorry if I misled you in any way. I prefer to delete my mess before it harms anybody else.

Comment: No big deal, it's a hard problem, apparently.  Thank you for the clarification.  I am thinking it might be better to try to give an explicit subbasis.

Answer (score 0):

This seems hopeless in general. Of course if $\tau_w$ and $\tau_n$ have the same compact sets then the only possible $\mathscr{C}$ is this common collection of compact sets and therefore any intermediate $\tau_\mathscr{C}$ will do the job (including $\tau_w$ and $\tau_n$ themselves). However, if there is at least one $A \subseteq X$ which is $\tau_w$-compact but not $\tau_n$-compact then the family $$\mathscr{C}=\{K : K \text{ is } \tau_n-\text{compact}\} \cup \{K \cup A : K \text{ is } \tau_n-\text{compact}\}  $$ satisfies i,ii and iii, but there is no intermediate $\tau_{\mathscr{C}}$ which has $\mathscr{C}$ as its compact sets.